# Debugging a Mac/Cocoa file descriptor leak

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, instruments, file-descriptor

My sandboxed Mac app is (apparently) leaking file resources (handles?). While adding files to it (and converting some of them to a different format), it will fail on an `-[NSFileManager copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:]` with this underlying error:

```
NSUnderlyingError=0x600000440a50 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Too many open files"
```

I can reliably reproduce this outside of Xcode (with the Debug build) but never inside. It looks like a file somewhere is being opened and never closed. It happens every time on the same file when I drop the same folder, or the next one if I take that file out. I logged each place I can think of where I'm doing file I/O outside of `NSFileManager`, and it looks like all of my open calls are balanced with closes, as are my calls to start and stop secure resource access on `NSURLs`.

1. Why won't this happen inside of Xcode?
2. How can I track down where the unbalanced calls are happening?
3. Is it possible that error is a red herring?

I tried running in Instruments outside of Xcode with the **File Activity** preset, and was able to reproduce the error in it, but it doesn't look like there is any way to get the information I need from the instruments employed (File Activity, Reads/Writes, File Attributes, Directory I/O).

Comment: Use Activity Monitor, select the process, View > Inspect Process, select the Open Files and Ports tab. Or do `sudo lsof -p <the PID of the process>`. See if you can tell what file or port is open too many times. Maybe that will make it obvious which part of the code is responsible. Probably, it doesn't fail when launched from Xcode because Xcode bumps up the resource limit for open file descriptors. See the `ulimit` shell built-in command and `getrlimit()` and `setrlimit()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was ultimately able to figure out the root cause using Instruments. I sorted the **File Attributes** instrument's Event List by the FD column, and was able to see that there were many "open" events for the same file descriptor (and some for the same file and different descriptors), without any "close" events. I was able to track down the offending code to a library I use. I reproduced it in the [unit tests](https://github.com/abbeycode/UnrarKit/blob/master/Tests/URKArchiveTests.m), using this method and comparing before and after some code was run:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfOpenFileHandles {
    int pid = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] processIdentifier];
    NSPipe *pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    NSFileHandle *file = pipe.fileHandleForReading;

    NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    task.launchPath = @"/usr/sbin/lsof";
    task.arguments = @[@"-P", @"-n", @"-p", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", pid]];
    task.standardOutput = pipe;

    [task launch];

    NSData *data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];
    [file closeFile];

    NSString *lsofOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//    NSLog(@"LSOF:\n%@", lsofOutput);

    return [lsofOutput componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]].count;
}
```